# How to protect web client ID in GCP source code

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

My GAE app publishes some APIs in GCP and uses the following structure:

```
# Replace the following lines with client IDs obtained from the APIs
# Console or Cloud Console.
WEB_CLIENT_ID = '????????????.apps.googleusercontent.com'

ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS = [WEB_CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID]
SCOPES = [endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE]

@endpoints.api(name=API_NAME,
               version=API_VERSION,
               description='An API to manage languages',
               allowed_client_ids=ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS,
               scopes=SCOPES)
```

My doubt is if someone picks this source code from my machine or GitHub project. He or she can access the APIs using the discovered web client id.

What’s the best practice in this case?

---

I acknowledge that the client can expose the ID and someone have access to it. But I believe that is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. One way is to always check in a default value for the client ID, so that when people check out your code, they have to modify it to deploy it. You can also move the client ID to its own module and not check it in at all, and make the expectation that they create their own module with their own client ID. This avoids having a modified state for a checked in file all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The client ID itself is not sufficient information to generate a valid token. The cryptography involved will prevent such a person from accessing your API.